# Google Sheets POST Request - Payload Too Large Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to do a POST request from a google sheet to a heroku server of 12 cells (total 488324 characters) using the following google apps script:

```
function sendInfoToApi() {
      const randomId = Math.random();
    
      var en1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('A3').getValues()[0][0];
      var en2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('A4').getValues()[0][0];
      var en3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('A5').getValues()[0][0];
      var en4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('A6').getValues()[0][0];
    
      var fr1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('B3').getValues()[0][0];
      var fr2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('B4').getValues()[0][0];
      var fr3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('B5').getValues()[0][0];
      var fr4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('B6').getValues()[0][0];
    
      var de1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('C3').getValues()[0][0];
      var de2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('C4').getValues()[0][0];
      var de3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('C5').getValues()[0][0];
      var de4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final").getRange('C6').getValues()[0][0];
    
      // 11111
      var data1 = {
        "title": randomId,
        "en1": en1
      }
      var payload1 = JSON.stringify(data1)  
      var url1 = 'https://ag-sheets-api.herokuapp.com/posts';
      var fetchParameters1 = {
          'method': 'post',
          'contentType': 'application/json', 
          'payload' : payload1,
          'muteHttpExceptions' : false
      };
      try {
          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, fetchParameters1);
          } catch(e){
            Logger.log(e)
      }
    
      // 22222
      var data2 = {
        "title": randomId,
        "en1": en2
      }
      var payload2 = JSON.stringify(data2)  
      var url2 = 'https://ag-sheets-api.herokuapp.com/posts/${randomId}';
      var fetchParameters2 = {
          'method': 'patch',
          'contentType': 'application/json', 
          'payload' : payload2,
          'muteHttpExceptions' : false
      };
      try {
          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, fetchParameters2);
          } catch(e){
            Logger.log(e)
      }
    
    
    }
```

I get this error when I send all 12 cells (or any more than 1 even):

```
Exception: Request failed for https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com returned code 413. Truncated server response: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Payload Too Large</pre>
</body>
</html>
 (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

The 12 cells is the final output of a massive delivery page of html for a website (50k characters). Because Google Sheets limit cells to 50000 characters I have to have 12 cells of the final html. What I'm trying to do is output the 12 cells to a server, store it in a database... and then create a front end somewhere that will do some concatenation and find/replace and uglify/minimise actions and spit out the final full html of the page so then anyone can do a simple copy paste and upload it to the company server.

As you can see to get around this issue i want to do one request at a time.. so I've attempted to do an initial Post request and then a patch request but I'm not seeing the patch part work.. is this the correct way to do a fetch patch request?

[Google apps script current limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)

My server patch code:

```
//UPDATE A POST
router.patch('/:postId', async (req,res) => {
  try {
    const updatedPost = await Post.updateOne(
      //{ _id:req.params.postId }, 
      { title:req.params.postId }, 
      { $set: {
        title: req.body.title,
        en1: req.body.en1,
        en2: req.body.en2,
        en3: req.body.en3,
        en4: req.body.en4,
        fr1: req.body.fr1,
        fr2: req.body.fr2,
        fr3: req.body.fr3,
        fr4: req.body.fr4,
        de1: req.body.de1,
        de2: req.body.de2,
        de3: req.body.de3,
        de4: req.body.de4 
      } }
    )
    res.json(updatedPost)
  }catch(err){
    res.json({ message: err })
  }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Have you checked whether making this request from somewhere else succeeds? Also, what about splitting this into several requests, so as to reduce the payload for each?

Comment: im trying to figure out how i could populate the same post on the database with 4 posts.. 1 post request and the rest patch im guessing

Comment: yeh cant figure it out.. will update the question

Comment: `I'm not seeing the patch part work`: can you be more specific? Are you getting any error? `patch` is a valid request method for UrlFetch, and I think you're using it correctly. Have you set up your server to listen to `patch` requests for this URL?

Comment: ok so i got it to work but every time i patch it it replaces the others with null.. how do i get it to patch only the one thats being sent and not the others?? I've added my server patch code

Comment: `it replaces the others with null` do you mean the data from the Mongo (it's Mongo right?) database?

Comment: yeah mondgodb atlas